# PHP __callStatic failing intermittently

Tags: php, methods, static-methods

I have a simple __callStatic magic method defined in my class:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
    if(substr($method, 0, 8) == "require_") {
          // do stuff
    }
}
```

The script dies with a fatal error "Undefined method MyClass::require_foo" when executed.

**However**..

If I modify the file in any way, for example:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
    if(substr($method, 0, 8) == "require_") {
          // HELLO
    }
}
```

It then works on the next page load. Subsequent page loads fail until I make another change to the file.

This is creepy, right? But 100% reproducible every time.

Comment: too little information to answer. please provide a reproducable test case

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. -- Just add another `public static function fooMooBuh($method, $args) {var_dump(__NAMESPACE__, __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $method, $args); die();}` and call that before you call yours. What does it give? For a second call, remove the `die()` and check if yours still isn't called. According to your information - as you have edited the file - it must work. Then with the third call, you should get your error again. Does this happen?

Comment: Also you are free everytime to invoke via `MyClass::__callStatic('require_foo', array());` as well. Sure it does exist?

Comment: Do you have any opcode caches running on your server...?

Comment: @hakre Your method results in Warning: Missing argument 1 for TestClass::fooMooBuh().

Comment: @deceze I'm definitely going to look into that. It has to be some kind of caching related issue, I'm thinking.

Comment: The following is 100% reproducible: `code`<?php 

class TestClass {
 
 public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
  echo "called $method";die();
 }
}require_once("TestClass.php");
TestClass::fail();`code` It works once, then fails with undefined method, then once TestClass is altered in anyway, it works again once.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was related to opcode caching on the server. eAccelerator has known issues with __callStatic(). https://eaccelerator.net/ticket/382